# Is it possible to have a custom error for a specific website path?

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm trying to figure out how to make a custom error for when a pdf does not exist in a path on my website. The url calling to the website would look something like "https://www.thisisawebsite.com/path/123455.pdf"

Now is there a way to make a custom error come up when a pdf can not be found in the /path/ folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I needed to do. I went into IIS and set up a custom 404 error page for the specific path where all the pdfs were. So whenever anyone tried to go to a pdf that didn't exist, they would hit the error page. A lot simpler than what I imagined.